# Scale with Kivy ScatterLayout Doesn't Behave as Expected

Tags: python, scroll, kivy, scale

I would like to zoom in and zoom out of a collection of widgets. I would also like to scroll. I tried to accomplish this with a `ScrollView` as the root widget and a `ScatterLayout` as the child.The widgets I'd like to zoom in and out of are children to the `ScatterLayout`. This isn't behaving as expected. Here's a minimal version.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.scatterlayout import ScatterLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView


kv = '''
#:kivy 1.11.1
<MyScatter>:
    do_translation_y: False
    do_rotation: False
    do_scale: False
    canvas:
        Color:
            hsv: .1, 1, .5
        Rectangle:
            size: 100, 100

<ScrollView>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 640, 480
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    scroll_type: ['bars']
    bar_width: 10
    bar_inactive_color: self.bar_color
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 0, 0
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<MyScatterLayout>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 1280, 720
    do_translation: False
    do_rotation: False
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
'''

Builder.load_string(kv)


class MyScatter(Scatter):
    pass


class MyScatterLayout(ScatterLayout):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = MyScatterLayout()
        layout.add_widget(MyScatter())
        root = ScrollView()
        root.add_widget(layout)
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

[image: child widget is outside scatterlayout]

When zooming out, the child of `ScatterLayout` ends up outside of the layout's bounds. I would expect all the children to stay within the layout's bounds no matter what the transformation is. What am I doing wrong?

Tangential to the question: when I zoom out enough that the ScatterLayout is smaller than the `ScrollView`, scrolling snaps the `ScatterLayout` to the origin (bottom left corner). Per the [ScrollView docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html?highlight=scroll%20view#managing-the-content-size-and-position) it looks like a `ScrollView`'s child is expected to be larger than the `ScrollView` itself. I assume to prevent this from happening I need to increase the size of the `ScatterLayout` as I scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to scale the size of the `ScatterLayout` for the children's position to be consistent. I've also incorporated [Nattosai Mito's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64572161/12644028).

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.scatterlayout import ScatterLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView


kv = '''
#:kivy 1.11.1
<MyScatter>:
    do_translation_y: False
    do_rotation: False
    do_scale: False
    canvas:
        Color:
            hsv: .1, 1, .5
        Rectangle:
            size: 100, 100

<MyScrollView>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 640, 480
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    scroll_type: ['bars']
    bar_width: 10
    bar_inactive_color: self.bar_color
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 0, 0
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<MyScatterLayout>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 1280 * self.scale, 720 * self.scale  # this is the correction
    do_translation: False
    do_rotation: False
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: 0, 0
            size: self.size
'''

Builder.load_string(kv)


class MyScatter(Scatter):
    pass


class MyScatterLayout(ScatterLayout):
    pass


class MyScrollView(ScrollView):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = MyScatterLayout()
        layout.add_widget(MyScatter())
        root = MyScrollView()
        root.add_widget(layout)
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is related to the issue, but `ScatterLayout` is a subclass of `Scatter` so its canvas instructions must be in local coordinates.

```yaml
<MyScatterLayout>:
    ...
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: 0, 0  # <- shold be this
            size: self.size
```

And you shouldn't write any rule for `ScrollView` because it affects all instances that might exist outside of your code. So instead, define a subclass and write a rule for it.

```
class MyScrollView(ScrollView):
    pass

<MyScrollView>:
    ...
```